# How to store array in the MySQL database in R

Tags: mysql, arrays, r

I have come across a problem where I need to store the array in the Mysql database using R.

For Example:

I have a vector

```
v = c(2,4,5,7,8,9,12,13,34,21,10)
```

and I want to add this into the mysql database.

Please tell me how I can store that and also let me know the what would be the table and its field for this in mysql database?

Comment: What have you tried already, what packages do you use to connect to the MySql database...

Comment: The lack of effort here is striking.  R (and S-Plus) have had a database interface for a dozen+ years and there are hundreds of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for `R mysql store blob` got me a lot of good links, for example:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2008q1/000423.html

Comment: But that has given in vague manner with respect to my question... I need also the table structure in mysql database with simple example if possible.Please help me out if anybody know this